# Enable Client-side logging — Socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, socket.io

How do I enable client-side logging in Socket.io (Socket.io-client)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just watched at the code at https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client, and I think there is no possibility to enable logging on the client side.

Comment: Well, I'd better post it as an issue there then.